# Is this the best way to make the <body> max-width and centered?

Tags: css

I want the content of a web page to be centered and max width of, say 900px.

From my research and testing, it looks like this is the way to do it, but I wanted to confirm:

```
<body style="max-width:900px; text-align:center;margin-left:auto ;margin-right:auto">
```

Obviously, you'd put the *style* in the CSS.

And I figure anybody with a big screen is going to have a fairly new browser.

Comment: Why a max-width and not a fixed width? Does "centered content" mean both centered body and centered body *text*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CSS:

```
body { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
#centerContainer { width: 900px; text-align: left; margin: 0px auto; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="centerContainer">Content</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 68):

Why use a wrapper unless and until you need it? I wouldn't wrap stuff nilly-willy just because you can, it adds up. Also, you can use the Body tag as a "free wrapper" if you want:

CSS:

```
html {
    margin:    0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}

body {
    /* whatever you want */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than make `<body>` *centered*, I would recommend to make a `<div>` as a *wrapper* or *container* with `width: 900px`.

---

`HTML:`

```
<body>
   <div id="container">

   **Your Contents**

   </div>
</body>
```

`CSS:`

```
body{
   width: 100%;
}
#container {
   width: 900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is by creating a wrapper div that will hold your content on the page.

CSS:

```
#wrapper{margin:0 auto; width:900px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper>

<!--content goes here-->

</div> <!--/wrapper-->
```

Comment: Why would you create a DIV wrapper instead of just applying the style to the <body> tag?

Comment: I would apply it to a DIV because I may want to add more styles to it. For example,  I want my body bg to be yellow and my centered main block of content ("wrapper") be blue. I guess whatever works best, both are ok to use. It depends on your end goal.

Comment: Why not just add a background to html, in that very special case?

Comment: Seems like it was a trend back in 2012 to wrap everything into wrapper elements and then wrap it once more just in case.

Comment: @ClayNichols, Because you may suddenly have a page where you want a full screen image or video. If you already put body in CSS with a max-width, you can't change that.  If you use a wrapping div, you can just omit the wrapping div.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing it on body, I would create a "wrapper" div and style it this way:

```
<div style="width: 900px; margin: auto;">Content</div>
```